# How to create separate elements in Zend\Form and set options to them

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I want to create them as objects and then assign options, smth like:

```
$name = new Zend\Form\Element\Text('name');
$name->setLabel('Your name:');
$name->setRequired(true); // does not work?
$this->add($name);
```

How it is possible set options like "required" one there, how to set validators? Framework throws exception "No method exists" for setRequired() one.

P.S. I really don't want to use array-style, it's quite annoying when you have tons of code in one array. I mean the following:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
        'label'      => 'Your email address:',
        'required'   => true,
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            'EmailAddress',
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood one thing, the validators not a part of element by default.

If you want an element contains some validators itself. You need to make the element implements InputProviderInterface such as

```
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;
class MyElement extends Element implements InputProviderInterface
{
    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        $spec = array(
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                'EmailAddress',
            )
        );

        return $spec;
    }
}
```

When form validation started, InputFilter of form will collect all validators from form elements and merge into final one.

However, you could also add/remove form validators dynamic by handle form InputFilter:

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$form->add($yourElement);
$filter = $form->getInputFilter();
$filter->remove('email');
$filter->add(array(
    'name' => 'email',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array (
        'EmailAddress'
    ),
));
$form->setInputFilter($filter);
$form->setData(array(
    'email' => 'abc',
));
$form->prepare();
echo $form->isValid();
print_r($form->getMessages());
```

Answer (score 0):

Zend form option setRequired true only worknig with the option validators.you have to define Validation rule to this element like this.

```
$this->review->addValidators(

array('NotEmpty',true, array( 'messages' => array( 'isEmpty' => "Please enter product Review.") ) )

);
```